# WakeUp Device when incoming_Sip call and answer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sip

The Window flags works great when the app is still in background, im able to wakeup the screen and trigger `InComingCallActivity` to receive SipCalls .

My question is how to wake up device when the app has been closed by the user and to achieve the same when the app is still in background(i.e when incoming call event is received by the `BroadcastReceiver` wake device and trigger corresponding intent ).Is the following the rightway to wakeUp device and open Intent.Please help!

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

And the following is my code for `IncomingCallReceiver` - where from this class i call `InComingCallActivity` for answering and rejecting calls.

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
/**
 * Processes the incoming call, answers it, and hands it over to the IncommingCallActivity.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The context under which the receiver is running.
 * @param intent
 *            The intent being received.
 */
String userName = null;
public SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager.getSessionInstance();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    // sipReg = new SipRegisteration(context);

    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                super.onRinging(call, caller);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEnded(call);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEstablished(call);
            }
        };
        incomingCall = sessionManager.mSipManager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);

        userName = incomingCall.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
        if (userName == null) {
            userName = incomingCall.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
        }

        showIncomingCall(intent, context);
        sessionManager.mCall = incomingCall;
        System.out.println(incomingCall);

        // sip..updateStatus(incomingCall);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.close();
        }
        Log.e("IncomingWakeful service", "" + e);
    }
}

/**
 * Handling incoming call and passing it to the IncomingCalActivity
 * 
 * @param intent
 * @param context
 */

private void showIncomingCall(Intent intent, Context context) {

    Intent intentCall = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);
    intentCall.putExtra("INCALL_USER_NAME", userName);
    context.startActivity(intentCall);

}

public void answerIncomingCall() {

    try {
        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        incomingCall.startAudio();
        if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
            incomingCall.toggleMute();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

public void rejectIncomingCall() {

    try {
        if (incomingCall != null) {

            incomingCall.endCall();
            incomingCall.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

**THE MANIFEST FILE AND PERMISSIONS**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.sip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.voip.sip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="true" />
```